# sql count on joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that there a a bazillion of these on here, but I have spent an hour reading them and trying.

All I need to do is return a count of order and items assigned to order.
Totals, not each.

So if I have 300 order with exactly 3 items per order I need a return of:

```sql
-- OrderCount: 300 ItemCount: 900

SELECT COUNT (o.id) AS OrderCount, COUNT (i.id) AS ItemCount
FROM order_detail o  JOIN item_detail i 
ON i.job_id = o.id 
WHERE o.customer_terminal_id = 182 AND o.requested_del_date = '2018-12-03'
```

This returns a count of everything and they are both the same.
I have tried with grouping as well.

Update:
This works:

```sql
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT o.id) AS OrderCount, COUNT (i.id) AS ItemCount
FROM order_detail o  JOIN item_detail i 
ON i.job_id = o.id 
WHERE o.customer_terminal_id = 182 AND o.requested_del_date = '2018-12-04'
```

but the real requirement is that some of the orders goto locations that have the same address.  What I really need is the count of those unique addresses.
They are in a table called Common_Address_points which is joined to orders by

o.Delivery_Location_Id = Common_Address_Points.id

So desired output would be Orders, unique addresses and items

So in the above if all of them were 1 order to 1 address, except for 1 that had 10 orders going to the same address it would show:

Orders: 300
Addresses: 290
Items: 900

I think this does it but I have to verify:

```sql
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT o.id) AS OrderCount, COUNT (i.id) AS ItemCount, COUNT (DISTINCT Common_Address_Point.Id) AS Addresses
FROM order_detail o  
JOIN item_detail i ON i.job_id = o.id 
JOIN Common_Address_Point ON Common_Address_Point.Id = o.Delivery_Location_Id
WHERE o.customer_terminal_id = 182 AND o.requested_del_date = '2018-12-04'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - you need to add distinct for order count - `COUNT (distinct o.id)`

```
SELECT COUNT (distinct o.id) AS OrderCount, COUNT (i.id) AS ItemCount
FROM order_detail o  JOIN item_detail i 
ON i.job_id = o.id 
WHERE o.customer_terminal_id = 182 AND o.requested_del_date = '2018-12-03'
```

Comment: thank you...that was step one.  Working on step two now!

Comment: @JoeRuder, what is step two?

Comment: sorry...they changed it on me after I posted the question.  I don't mind posting as a new question if you would prefer.

Comment: @JoeRuder, so what is your actual desired output? could please add your desired result in your question